# Set source data of chart to equal a range defined by a variable

Tags: vba, excel

For anybody that is interested, this now works for me. I think the problem I had earlier was that I was using .select and this was causing issues

```
Public Sub updateChart()
```

'Searches for today's date and selects everything for the last 12 months

```
Dim month
Dim year
Dim stringToFind
Dim newRange
Dim foundString
Dim newRange1
Dim newrange2
```

'Assign a value to the month and the year

```
month = VBA.DateTime.month(Date)
year = VBA.DateTime.year(Date)
```

'Make the search for string equal to the month + year variables

```
stringToFind = month & "/" & year
```

'Declare a range where you will look for the month and year

```
Set newRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C16:Z16")
```

'Search for the month and year

```
Set foundString = newRange.Find(stringToFind)
```

'Once the correct date has been found, resize the range to be the new data source - had to do this in two stages because could not use a - col number on the resize

```
Set newRange1 = foundString.Offset(0, -12)

Set newrange2 = newRange1.Resize(2, 12)
```

'Update the chart with the new data source

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").ChartObjects("chartName").Chart.SetSourceData 
Source:=newrange2


End Sub
```

Public Sub updateChart()

```
' Searches for today's date and selects everything for the last 12 months

Dim rgFound As Range
Dim month
Dim year
Dim stringToFind
Dim newRange
Dim newRange1
Dim newRange2

month = VBA.DateTime.month(Date)
year = VBA.DateTime.year(Date)

stringToFind = month & "/" & year


Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

Set rgFound = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C16:z17").Find(stringToFind)

Set newRange = rgFound.Offset(0, -12)

Set newRange1 = newRange.Resize(2, 12)
```

newRange1 now holds a series of dates in row 16 (as text so my find worked) and corresponding values in row 17

```
Charts("Chart1").SetSourceData Source:=newRange1
```

I am trying to set the source data to newRange1 for chart1, but it returns an error: subscript out of range. The chart is on a different sheet to the information stored in newRange1. I am not sure how to set newRange1 to be the new source data for chart1 - any help would be much appreciated!

```
End Sub
```

Comment: Check that `rgFound` is actually finding a value in column 13 or higher.

Comment: rgFound = nothing, but when I go through each line (comment out the one below), and call .select on rgFound, newRange and newRange1, it all works... Do you know why this is?

Comment: If you don't find `stringToFind` then `rgFound` is nothing and the `newRange` and `newRange1` lines will error.

Comment: Do you have an `On Error` statement anywhere?

Comment: stringToFind finds the correct date, and my range is selected. And no, no On Error anywhere - Is it because the range is a variable? The error I get is that subscript is out of range

Comment: Try `Debug`, add at the end of the code `Debug.Print rgFound.Address` and `Debug.Print newRange1.Address` , and see what strings are you getting

Comment: Debug.print for both variables = rgFound is $Q&16, which on sheet1 is where today's date is, and newRange1 is $E$16:$P$17 on the same sheet, which are the dates and values for the last 12 months

Comment: Does this work? `Charts("Chart1").SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").range(newRange1.address)`

Comment: Afraid not, it still errors and says subscript out of range